# What should I do to not show the legend for all the plots?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Here is my code:

```
N=100;
n=50;
tau=0.001;
h=0.01;
lambda=tau/h;
mu=lambda/2;
u=zeros(N,n);
u1=zeros(N,n);
u2=zeros(N,n);
phi=zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:N
        u(j,i)=cos(2*pi*i*(j-1)*h);
        u1(j,i)=cos(2*pi*i*((j-1)*h-tau));
    end

    for j=2:N
        u2(j,i)=u(j,i)-lambda*(u(j,i)-u(j-1,i));
    end
u2(1)=0;
phi(i,1)=2*pi*i/N;    
end
uf=zeros(n,1);
uf1=zeros(n,1);
uf2=zeros(n,1);

for i=1:n
   for j=1:N
       uf(i,1)=uf(i,1)+(u(j,i)*exp(-1i*(j-1)*phi(i,1)))/100;
       uf1(i,1)=uf1(i,1)+u1(j,i)*exp(-1i*j*phi(i,1))/100;
       uf2(i,1)=uf2(i,1)+(u2(j,i)*exp(-1i*(j-1)*phi(i,1)))/100;
   end
end
final=zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    final(i,1)=-(h/(1i*tau))*(log(uf2(i)/uf(i)));
end


figure;
hold on 
z=1:1:n;
b = real(final(z,1));
%plot(phi(z,1),b,'o');
c = imag(final(z,1));
%plot(phi(z,1),c,'-');
%plot(phi(z,1),0,'-');
plot(phi(z,1),b,'ro',phi(z,1),c,'ko',phi(z,1),0,'k-');
legend('Real','Imaginary');
legend ('Location','NorthWest');
xlabel('Reduced Wavenumber')
ylabel('Modified Wavenumber')
```

I am plotting a line at y=0 for reference. I do not want them in legend. But I am getting this figure:
[image]
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you change your code so that it is reproducible? As it stands many variables are undefined

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685967/how-to-show-legend-for-only-a-specific-subset-of-curves-in-the-plotting

Comment: Same question in general, but the specifics allow for another approach here, hence I wouldn't close it as duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of plotting everything with one `plot`-command, do it like this:

```
plot(phi(z,1),b,'ro'); hold on
plot(phi(z,1),c,'ro'); hold on
plot(phi(z,1),0,'k-'); hold off

legend('Real','Imaginary','Location','NorthWest');
xlabel('Reduced Wavenumber')
ylabel('Modified Wavenumber')
```

You shouldn't have problems then.

The actual reason is, that the legend is called differently in this case. The more elegant solution offers the [answer of Magla.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18896615/2605073)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `plot` command, it is your change in how `legend` is called that gives the effect.

Answer (score 3):

Legends in matlab should be called like this

```
plot(phi(z,1),b,'ro',phi(z,1),c,'ko',phi(z,1),0,'k-');
legend( {'Real','Imaginary'} , 'Location', 'NorthWest');
```

where legend labels are stored in a cell array of strings `{...}`. `Location` is a parameter to be placed either with the legend call (like in the above code) or outside the function by using the `set` function

```
h = legend({'Real','Imaginary'});
set(h, 'Location','NorthWest');
```

This gives

[image]